# break in PHP when called in a function

Tags: php, break

I have a page that is taking a result from a MySQL query and passing it to a function. The function in turn has a nested while. If I call "break 2" in the nested function will it exit the function and continue through the MySQL array (re-calling the function)?

```
function loopingFunction($val,$start,$stop) {
    $strSQL = "SELECT ID FROM table WHERE someval = $val";
    $rs1    = mysql_query($strSQL);
    while($r1 = mysql_fetch_array($rs1) {
         $strSQL = "SELECT ID FROM newTable WHERE someval = '".$r1["ID"]."'";
         $rs2    = mysql_query($strSQL);
         while($r2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs2) {
             if($start >= $stop) {
                  break 2;
             }
             do something
             $start ++;
         }
    }
}
.....
$strSQL = "SELECT myVar FROM myTable WHERE ID = $x";
$rsMain = mysql_query($strSQL);
while($rsM = mysql_fetch_array($rsMain)) {
    loopingFunction($val,0,200);
}
```

Comment: Try `return;` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help you. You can use the return in place of break 2.

```
function loopingFunction($val,$start,$stop) {
    $strSQL = "SELECT ID FROM table WHERE someval = $val";
    $rs1    = mysql_query($strSQL);
    while($r1 = mysql_fetch_array($rs1) { 
         $strSQL = "SELECT ID FROM newTable WHERE someval = '".$r1["ID"]."'";
         $rs2    = mysql_query($strSQL);
         while($r2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs2) {
             if($start >= $stop) {
                  return; 
             }
             do something
             $start ++;
         }
    }
}
.....
$strSQL = "SELECT myVar FROM myTable WHERE ID = $x";
$rsMain = mysql_query($strSQL);
while($rsM = mysql_fetch_array($rsMain)) {
    loopingFunction($val,0,200);
}
```